# For new AWS instance, "Using username "ubuntu". Server refused our key."

Tags: ssh, login, amazon-ec2, aws, remote-login

I have been using Amazon EC2 instances in AWS.  I have been successful connecting with WinSCP to a variety of instances, including Amazon Linux, Rocky Linux, SUSE, and CentOS 6, 7, and 8.  All of those instances with other OSs have succeeded using a particular combination of

- Key pair (login)
- VPC
- Subnet
- Firewall (security group)

Therefore, it does not seem to be plausible that any of those choices are at fault.

In WinSCP, I can clone working WinSCP configurations from other instances and then (after adjusting the new site for the changed "Host name" and using the suggested login username of "ubuntu") I can try to connect just like I would for the others that worked.  Therefore, it does not seem to be plausible that the problem is an incorrect WinSCP configuration (unless I should be using something other than "ubuntu" as the default username).

The instance is seen, but the attempt to login fails for the Ubuntu instance only.

> No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

and

> Using username "ubuntu".
> Server refused our key.
> Authentication failed.

I've looked through some of the other questions that have to do with "Server refused our key", but this isn't a problem with the key pair itself, since it works with many other instances.  Nor does it seem feasible that it could be any of the other common elements that have been working for other instances.  The error message itself indicates that it did see the recommended login username of "ubuntu" (and I even tried other usernames that are sometimes used for AWS instance logins such as ec2-user, admin, root, but those didn't work either).

I've also tried creating a second instance to check if there was some fluke or mistake about making the first instance, but there was no difference.

Since this failed login is for the initial login attempt to the default user, I cannot login as a different user and poke around inside or change the instance.

If it matters, I was using

**Minimal Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Jammy**
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-o5bowpuwmx3ng

UPDATE 1: The same happens for
**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS - Jammy**
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-f2if34z3a4e3i

I wonder if there is something different in how Ubuntu handles the communication that requires a different setting than any other OS that has worked.

UPDATE 2: Based on a clue from the answer by [rahul jain](https://askubuntu.com/users/1594770/rahul-jain), I tried a quick test using an instance based on the previous Minimal Ubuntu LTS release.

**Minimal Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Focal**
https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-meawmysinhrrs

That one worked fine.  Therefore, it does seem that the issue is a change since 20.04 Focal Fossa, and it seems likely that it is related to authentication changes that require a more recent PuTTY codebase, as rahul jain suggested.  I will do more testing, but the answer is looking good so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try updating putty to the latest version i was using an older version updated it to 0.76 and it worked flawlessly
[https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/)

hope this helps

Eric adds:
For those like myself who are using WinSCP, the equivalent solution is to upgrade to WinSCP version 5.20 (or later).  At this time, 5.20 is still in beta.  (Currently the latest release is 5.19.6)

"WinSCP 5.20 is a major application update. New features and enhancements include:

...
SSH core upgraded to PuTTY 0.76. That includes support rsa-sha2-256 and rsa-sha2-512 SSH public key algorithms. ..." Excerpt from [All Downloads for WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/downloads.php).

With the help of the answer and suggestion by rahul jain, I was able to isolate the problem to WinSCP and then find this related bug report.

["Server refused our key" after updating to Ubuntu 22.04 beta on a LAMP stack](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32133)

That WinSCP issue points to related issue "[Bug 1952 – Support rsa-sha2-256 and rsa-sha2-512 SSH public key algorithms](https://winscp.net/tracker/1952)"

PuTTY 0.76 worked for rahul jain, likely because its SSH processing has been upgraded (e.g. version 0.75 added "Upgraded default SSH key fingerprint format to OpenSSH-style SHA-256. Upgraded private key file format to PPK3, with improved passphrase hashing and no use of SHA-1.")

The "Known Issues" in [Release Notes for **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)**](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668) led to this related GitHub issue that describes how "[openssh deprecates ssh-rsa key type ...](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/11783)"
Excerpt:
"It is now possible to perform chosen-prefix attacks against the
SHA-1 algorithm for less than USD$50K. For this reason, we will be
disabling the "ssh-rsa" public key signature algorithm by default in a
near-future release."

And
"Distributions are picking up on this and deprecating ssh-rsa. Fedora did this recently and it will land in the next major Fedora release. ..."

Presumably, the 22.04 release of Ubuntu has similarly deprecated the older, less secure standard for SSH authentication for similar reasons, which requires other client software to step up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will experiment with that soon.  The latest WinSCP (5.19.6) has
SSH and SCP code based on PuTTY 0.74+
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/
The changes in 0.75 and 0.76 are given here.
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/changes.html
Are you aware of anything about the latest Ubuntu (Jammy) that might be dependent on any of those SSH related changes in PuTTY 0.75 or 0.76?  (Other Linux distros, e.g. Rocky Linux, Amazon Linux, etc., do not seem to be bothered by using PuTTY 0.74+.)

Comment: Thank you so much! WinSCP 5.19 fails, WinSCP 5.20 RC3 works.

Answer (score 2):

Due to an update of the openssh-server package, the newer versions do not support the "ssh-rsa" algorithm, see here -> https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8

```
# tail -f /var/log/auth.log
Jun  9 22:37:31 ip-yy-yy-yy-yy sshd[15652]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
Jun  9 22:37:31 ip-yy-yy-yy-yy sshd[15652]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu zz.zz.zz.zz port 60931 [preauth]
```

You can update your ssh client and/or add the lines below to /etc/ssh/sshd.conf.

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

And restart your sshd

```
service sshd restart
```

To avoid the chicken/egg problem (since you can't access it) you can use a little "trick" with Docker (you'll need docker installed on your machine)

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/homeuser ubuntu /bin/bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
405f018f9d1d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:b6b83d3c331794420340093eb706a6f152d9c1fa51b262d9bf34594887c2c7ac
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
# apt update && apt install openssh-client -y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4653 B]
...
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/rcp.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/scp.1.gz (of link group rcp) doesn't exist
Setting up libxext6:amd64 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Setting up xauth (1:1.1-1build2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3) ...
# cd /homeuser/
# ssh ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx -i your-keypair.pem 
The authenticity of host 'xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1004-aws x86_64)
```

With this, you'll be able to access your box.

Comment: I started a new instance (Ubuntu) and was not able to connect until I saw your comment. That line in the sshd_config file solved for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons your new AWS instance is refusing your key. It could be an issue with the key itself, the permissions on the key, or the way the key is being used. One thing to check is the permissions on the key. Ensure that the key has the correct permissions for the user you are trying to connect with. Also, check to see if the key is being used correctly. For example, if you use an SSH key, ensure that you use the correct format for the key (i.e., ssh-rsa). ClearScale (https://www.clearscale.com) may help you find answers to your questions, or you can contact Amazon support for help. Cheers!