# Putty 0.76 does not work on Ubuntu 22.04 unless with Sudo

Tags: ssh, 22.04, putty

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04, and installed **PuTTY 0.76** in it.
Sorry, I can't remember if I used ***apt install*** or a ***snap***.

Putty initiates OK,  but when attempting a terminal session with an open, nothing happens.
Apparently Putty just terminates.
But I discovered that if I **run Putty with sudo in a terminal session**, it behaves properly.
As well, a simple SSH terminal ***without sudo*** is able to initiate a terminal session in the object machines.

I have been using Putty 0.76 in older versions of Ubuntu satisfactorily up to now.

Comment: any error message that would help ?

Comment: @Marco   Thanx for the suggestion. I found a Putty log and it said "Unable to load server:fixed" whatever that is....

Comment: Close to this one: https://askubuntu.com/q/1255916/57576

Comment: See Answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1407965/767949

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PuTTY: "unable to load font" in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255916/putty-unable-to-load-font-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 5):

It seems the default font for PuTTY 0.76 in Ubuntu 22.04 is **"Server:Fixed"**.
Not sure what that is, but I browsed the available fonts in PuTTY, and chose one to my liking.
Now PuTTY is working OK!
Thanx, @Marco-  Yes, **ALWAYS check those logs**!

[image]
Don't forget to go back to the session and save to persist the change.

Comment: Had the same issue, your solution of changing the font worked. Thanks.